# initializing a struct containing a slice of structs in golang

Tags: go, struct, slice

I have a struct that I want to initialize with a slice of structs in golang, but I'm trying to figure out if there is a more efficient version of appending every newly generated struct to the slice:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

type LuckyNumber struct {
    number int
}

type Person struct {
    lucky_numbers []LuckyNumber
}

func main() {
    count_of_lucky_nums := 10
    // START OF SECTION I WANT TO OPTIMIZE
    var tmp []LuckyNumber
    for i := 0; i < count_of_lucky_nums; i++ {
        tmp = append(tmp, LuckyNumber{rand.Intn(100)})
    }
    a := Person{tmp}
    // END OF SECTION I WANT TO OPTIMIZE
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Comment: more efficient how? Do you just want to skip the tmp variable? https://play.golang.org/p/XKg4VouoUI

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`make()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make) to allocate the slice in "full-size", and then use a [`for range`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) to iterate over it and fill the numbers:

```
tmp := make([]LuckyNumber, 10)
for i := range tmp {
    tmp[i].number = rand.Intn(100)
}
a := Person{tmp}
fmt.Println(a)
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/34JCCo8mVe).

Note that inside the `for` I did not create new "instances" of the `LuckyNumber` struct, because the slice already contains them; because the slice is not a slice of pointers. So inside the `for` loop all we need to do is just use the struct value designated by the [index expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) `tmp[i]`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `make()` the way icza proposes, you can also use it this way:

```
tmp := make([]LuckyNumber, 0, countOfLuckyNums)
for i := 0; i < countOfLuckyNums; i++ {
    tmp = append(tmp, LuckyNumber{rand.Intn(100)})
}
a := Person{tmp}
fmt.Println(a)
```

This way, you don't have to allocate memory for `tmp` several times: you just do it once, when calling make. But, contrary to the version where you would call `make([]LuckyNumber, countOfLuckyNums)`, here, `tmp` only contains initialized values, not uninitialized, zeroed values. Depending on your code, it might make a difference or not.

Comment: I think your answer works too, but why would the other answer allocate memory for tmp more than once?

Comment: The slice `tmp` is empty initially.  When you first append to it, the runtime allocates a small underlying array and places the value in it.  As you keep appending to the slice, once it reaches the capacity of the allocated underlying array, the runtime must allocate a new larger array and move everything from the first over to the new one.  It has to do this several times to accommodate the repeated appends (in this case, 4 allocations: https://play.golang.org/p/_ameESD2-o).

Comment: Oh, and the other answer avoids that repeated allocation as well (Fabien was referring to your version in the OP with that remark).  The other answer, however, sets the length of the slice equal to `countOfLuckyNums` in the `make()` call, while Fabien's version allocates an underlying array of that size but retains a slice length of 0.  This may be important if you interrupt the append sequence early for some reason.  Example: https://play.golang.org/p/bIs1jmEhrp